Решение задачи через цикл DO While С#
Даны числовой ряд и некоторое число ε. Найти сумму тех членов ряда, модуль которых больше или равен заданному е. Общий член ряда имеет вид:a_n=n!/(2^n )!
Факториал должен вычисляться без метода, в теле цикла do while.
Попытался сам, но увы все слишком плачевно(
Во время выполнения кода, получается что при a_n = 1 и е = 0,01, программа вывод результат и заканчивает работу, хотя должна выдавать результат когда будет a_n <= e, то есть она игнорирует цикл do while. Почему так происходит?
 using System;
    
    class PP_10
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите эллипс: ");
            double e = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            double sum = 0;
            int n = 0;
            int a_n = 0;
            int FactA = 0;
            int FactB = 0;
            do
            {
                if (n == 0)
                    FactA = 1;
                else
                    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
                    {
                        FactA *= i;
                    }
                int b = (int)Math.Pow(2, n);
                if (n == 0)
                {
                    FactB = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= b; i++)
                    {
    
                        FactB *= b;
    
                    }
                }
                a_n = FactA / FactB;
                if (a_n >= e)
                {
                    sum = sum + a_n;
                    n = n + 1;
                }
            } while (a_n <= e);
 Console.WriteLine($"Сумма членов ряда с модулем больше или равным {e} равна: {sum}");
               
        }
    }



как задать хороший вопрос 2. как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример


Что именно плачевно то? В целом выглядит нормально, единственное что нужно доделать - вычисление очередного члена ряда через предыдущий. Хотя бы для составляющих дроби сначала по отдельности подумайте, как это сделать. Не нужно каждый раз с единицы считать факториал на каждой итерации цикла, нужно считать с предыдущего значения до текущего только, это будет гораздо более оптимально.

Посмотрите ответ по метке ряды

Формулировка: "Найти сумму тех членов ряда модуль которых больше или равен заданному е" и код: while (a_n <= e) - не видите ли вы в этом противоречия? Ну ладно, модуль пропустили, тут он не актуален. Но само условие. В while указывается условие продолжения цикла, а не условие его прерывания. Условие прерывания цикла указывается в конструкции do ... until, которая есть, кажется, в Pascal, но в C# такой конструкции вроде нет.
